# Microphone to use with OS X's Speech features

Tags: microphone

I'm currently using the built-in microphone on my early 2007 MacBook Pro to access the Speech features.  I'd like to use an actual microphone that I can clip to my shirt or something (since Speech seems to work better when I'm closer to the mic).  What do you use for a mic?  Can I just use the mic on the default iPhone headphones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure the iPhone headphones with the built-in microphone will work on older MacBooks, since I believe they do require a headphone jack capable of sending the microphone input. Headphone jacks on MacBooks shipped after the iPhone was introduced all have that capability.

As fas as microphone recommendations, the following two seem to be regarded as very good by different sources I trust, such as the [Equipment Guide](http://hivelogic.com/articles/podcasting-equipment-guide-2009) that 5by5's Dan Benjamin writes every year:

- For beginners: Plantronics .Audio 655 USB Multimedia Headset
- For pros:  Heil PR40 Dynamic Microphone

Hope this helps.